# How can I use an observableobject class in an observableobject on SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I attached an image. Please see it.

[image: 1]

As far as I know the "View" is only view. It's not controller.
So Im developing like Way 1.
But I faced a problem that how can I use observableobject in another observableobject?

I thought if I pass a parameter with the observableobject the problem will be clean.
But I think it is bad way..

So I thought way 2.
But the way is the "View" is not only view. It is view and controller.

So Im confused the way2 is bad way or not.

Which way is good way? and Im wondering other SwiftUI developers how to develop about this case.

Please advice me if you think there is better way than way1 & way2.

**Summary**

Q1. Way1 - How can I use observableobject in another observableobject? (singltone? like static shared)

Q2. Way2 - Is it correct way? (View = view + controller)

Q3. Your advice.

**Env**

Xcode 14.2

Swift 5.7.2

Comment: as a swift UI developer what I prefer is having 2 Observable objects in a view and on receive changing the variable in another object to it will not conflict your structure and your view will only be view and code will be much cleaner

Comment: @NoorAhmedNatali Thanks for your answer. Could you give me some codes? Is your meaning is Binding parameter variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the sample code for your question:

```
struct MainView: View {
     @StateObject var mainVM = MainViewModel()
     @ObservedObject var discoveryVM:DiscoveryViewModel

     var body: some View {
           ZStack {
                ScrollView {
                     // if data changed in DiscoveryViewModel view will automatically upadte
                     ForEach(discoveryVM.showProfiles, id: \.self) { profile in
                          MyView(profile: Profile)
                     }
                }
           }
           .onReceive(discoveryVM.$toggle) { status in 
           // change something in MainViewModel when toggle in DiscoveryViewModel
                mainVM.toggle = status // change variable(rearly used)
                mainVM.doSomething() // call fucntions
           }
     }
}


class MainViewModel: ObservableObject {
     @Published var toggle: Bool = false
     
     func doSomething() {
        print("Do something")
     }
}



class DiscoveryViewModel: ObservableObject {
     @Published var data: [ProfileModel] = []
     @Published var toggle: Bool = false
}
```

`ObservableObjects` are mostly used where there is nesting of views

Answer (score 0):

SwiftUI is a new architecture, old design patterns don't really fit. In SwiftUI the `View` struct isn't the view in the MVC sense, that view layer (e.g. UIView/NSView objects) is generated automatically for us based diffing the `View` structs which are super fast efficient value types. View state is held in property wrappers like `@State` which essentially makes the value behave like an object, e.g. it has a "memory". You can pass this down to sub-Views as `let` for read access or `@Binding var` for write access, SwiftUI will track dependencies and call `body` on the affected `View` structs when necessary.

Normally in SwiftUI we only have a single `ObservableObject` that holds the model structs in `@Published` properties. Usually there are 2 singletons, one `shared` that loads from disk and another `preview` pre-loaded with test data for driving SwiftUI previews. This object is shared across View structs using `.environmentObject`

If you attempt to use multiple `ObservableObject` for view data instead of `@State` you'll run into major problems, actually the kind of consistency problems that SwiftUI's use of value types was designed to eliminate.